# How can I figure out why ASP.NET web api access token expired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web service implemented by ASP.NET WEB API 2.0 and secure it with bearer token as as described in article [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api).

And I set the expiry period to 180 days using code

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
```

However, I found that my token expired before 30 days end.

How can I found why my token expired?
And what detail does the access token contain? How can I parse the bearer token?

I host my web server in Azure web apps.

Thanks.

Comment: How to decode the bearer token http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800238/manually-decode-oauth-bearer-token-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701398/oauth2-webapi-token-expiration/33742210#33742210

Comment: Also check [why_not's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29144755/5588347)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use https://jwt.io/ to decode the bearer token once you have created one.

Examine the expiry date on the token matches what you are expecting.